# My staging takes longtime and displays connection timed out, but live site works on same IP

Tags: magento-2.1, staging

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09Wzh.png)

Please help, 
Firstly I got the attached error on the site and now since yesterday my staging site is not working.

***Live site is hosted on digital ocean, Ubuntu and the only change made yesterday on live site is that I created a sudo user for root, enabled firewall and change upload_max_limit to 8MB for image file upload in apache2 > PHP.ini file.***

The staging site was anyway not working prior than that but was giving error, But now it just keeps searching and returns with time out.

Need help please to resolve it. Any test file is also not working.

[image]

Comment: give 777 permission to `var` folder. `sudo chmod -R 777 var/*`

Comment: Thank you. I tried disabling UFW and now have the attached error.  Fatal error: Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir "/var/www/html/staging/var/cache/" is not writable in /var/www/html/staging/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/staging/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(180):

Comment: Execute on staging: `sudo chmod -R 777 var/*`

Answer (score 0):

Give `777` permission to `var` folder.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/*
```

Comment: Thank you very much. it is resolved.